# db2 aggregate sum() returns +++++++++ as value. When output details, sum of values is correct

Tags: sql, aggregate, db2-400

I've run into an issue and have been spinning my wheels for 2 days and have no solution in sight. Task is replacing an RPG report with a SQL based report on an iSeries server.  I can't read RPG and don't have a resource that can investigate the old code to see if / how it works around the issue.

Can't find anything on Google for queries returning plus signs ('+++++++') for the value (aggregate or otherwise).  Also not covered in my 'Understanding DB2' or 'DB2 Fundamentals' books.

I can extrapolate that issue is data related but, whatever the cause, I haven't yet found how to filter it out.

My report is aggregating inventory cost but prints $0 value for 2 of the 6 locations.

Using SQL to investigate found root cause is with a specific field (IDCOST).

Here is a query that illustrates the issue and some of my work around attempts:

```
SELECT T1.BRANCH,
DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END)                           ),12,0) AS ONHAND,

DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * T1.IDCOST               ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST, 
DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * IFNULL(T1.IDCOST,0)     ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST2, 
DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * COALESCE(T1.IDCOST,0)   ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST3, 
DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * (CASE WHEN T1.IDCOST IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T1.IDCOST END) ),12,0) AS ONHAND_COST4, 
DECIMAL(SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * .01                     ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST5

FROM LIBNAME.TABLENAME T1 WHERE T1.OHQTY > 1 AND T1.IDCOST >= 0
GROUP BY T1.BRANCH
```

Here are the results of this query:

```
BRANCH  ONHAND      ONHAND_COST     ONHAND_COST2    ONHAND_COST3    ONHAND_COST4    ONHAND_COST5
AA      8573338     3920833         3920833         3920833         3920833         85733   
BB      69076846    ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  690768  
CC      1114322     504469          504469          504469          504469          11143   
DD      33716759    ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++  337167  
EE      17433207    7748328         7748328         7748328         7748328         174332  
FF      2719417     1475488         1475488         1475488         1475488         27194
```

I'm getting plus signs in all variations of the the cost calculation, so I expect the problem isn't null values.  This field is identical to the prior (onhand) with the additional multiplication of the cost field.

In example #5, when multiplying against a known value (.01) the result is as expected (onhand / 100).

Because IDQMLL is only additional field (from previous calc) this is where I've been trying to find a work around.

When I output detail records instead of aggregating the totals and output that to an Excel spreadsheet I don't have any bad data and can create a pivottable and get report totals that match the RPG report.

Something in the aggregation is failing and reporting plus signs.  Trying to include only non-null data and cost values within normal ranges hasn't seemed to help.

Has anyone got advice for troubleshooting the '+++++++++' result values?

Answer (score 0):

+++++ means there's something unexpected...

Possibly the value overflowed/underflowed...

Try taking the outer cast to `DECMIAL(...,12,0)` off and see what Db2 wants to return.

FYI: NULLs would be returned in the greenscreen STRSQL as ---------

**EDIT**
what version of IBM i?   (Much) older versions only supported a max of 32 digits, newer versions support 63 and while your values are less than that it's possible that the size of the original columns means that the possible size resulting from your calculations is larger than that.

Welcome to the world of fixed decimal arithmetic.  The rules for determining decimal precision can be found here, [Decimal arithmetic in SQL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzdecarithmetic.htm)

Try wrapping the calculations in the `DECIMAL(...,12,0)` cast..

```
SELECT T1.BRANCH,
SUM( DECIMAL(CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END)                           ),12,0) AS ONHAND,

SUM( DECIMAL((CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * T1.IDCOST               ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST, 
SUM( DECIMAL((CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * IFNULL(T1.IDCOST,0)     ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST2, 
SUM( DECIMAL((CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * COALESCE(T1.IDCOST,0)   ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST3, 
SUM( DECIMAL((CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * (CASE WHEN T1.IDCOST IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T1.IDCOST END) ),12,0) AS ONHAND_COST4, 
SUM( DECIMAL((CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * .01                     ),12,0)  AS ONHAND_COST5

FROM LIBNAME.TABLENAME T1 WHERE T1.OHQTY > 1 AND T1.IDCOST >= 0
GROUP BY T1.BRANCH
```

Comment: Thanks but got the same thing without the decimal() wrapper.  Other numbers had 10 decimal places but the plus signs were still being returned.  Outputting rows to excel and summing costs results in about $25M with no cost values out of ordinary.  As if aggregate function including something that is not otherwise included.

Answer (score 0):

@Charles thanks for pointing me in the direction of casting my variable into  fixed precision!  Here is updated code that works.

```
SUM( (CASE T1.IDTYPE WHEN 'S' THEN (T1.OHQTY * T1.WGTFACTOR / 1000) ELSE T1.OHQTY END) * CAST(T1.IDCOST AS DECIMAL(32,12))) AS ONHAND_COST
```

I will add decimal(...,12,0) to final result but not needed to explain correction.